# Unable to see Image name and Tag in docker images

Tags: docker

I have created a docker Image, but in the Repository/Tag its showing as "None", please let me know what will be the reason.

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
none                       none              bhc0b0d2e67f        20 hours ago
```

Answer (score 0):

How have you built your docker image?

In order to give a tag to your image, as [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/),you have to write the command like:

`docker build -t yourimage:yourtag -f yourdockerfile context/of/image`

If you have already a docker image (like in your case) and you want to assign a tag to it:

`docker tag bhc0b0d2e67f TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]`

Comment: Really appreciate for quick response. In my company we have to use the predefined set of commands so we will be using this command in comman to build all the images & it usually works fine - but unfortunately having issue for this time "docker build –t imagename:tagname ."

Comment: docker build –t <imagename>:<tagname> .

Comment: I am not sure how it goes like that, but when I fire the docker with tag name & existing image id made the modification.